# How can there be no Thévenin voltage with only a dependent voltage source?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, thevenin, nodal-analysis

I don't understand why the Thévenin equivalent is equal to zero in this case because, if the load is a resistance, then yes, the circuit would be dead as there would be no voltage drop across Vx. But if there is a voltage or current source in the load section then the circuit would have power (not dead) and therefore there'd be a voltage drop across Vx, so the dependent source would have a voltage produced over it, therefore negating the fact that Vth is equal to 0 in this case.

*My question is: Why is there no Thévenin source if there are cases when the dependent source would have voltage over it.*

Update: point B is the lower wire point.
The circuit is equivalent to only a resistor, no Thevenin voltage equivalent.

Edit: I don't know what more detail to add, I just want to know why if there is a voltage source in the load circuit between points A and B, then wouldn't that case a current through the resistor Vx? Therefore, that would active the dependent source and Vth would no longer be 0.

[image: The circuit]

Comment: Where's terminal B?

Comment: As there is no source voltage or current in the circuit, it is only equivalent to a "resistance" ... equal to 0.933.. Ohm ...

Comment: Antonio51, I understand it in the case when there is only a resistor as a load. But, what if there is voltage or current source in the load section? Wouldn't that cause current through the resistor over Vx therefore there will be a voltage over the dependent source and Vth will no longer be zero.

Comment: here is a Maple sheet ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/vavmf.png and simulation https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV0FY.png No problem in question.

Comment: If there were an independent "voltage source and/or current source" in the "load", then the problem would be "different" and the Vth would be different of zero.

Comment: @Antonio51 But, I learnt that Thevenin's theorem can be used to simplify any linear circuit or portion of circuit so that you don't have to re-analyze the whole circuit as long as it's linear. I don't think you can have a 'different' problem because, the resulting circuit is supposed to act exactly like the previous un-simplified one in terms of voltage and current. Just to clarify, by load I mean the bit between points A & B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit is composed only of linear components - impedances and a linear dependent voltage source. Hence the overall circuit is linear. From the linearity of the circuit, it follows that the voltage across the A-B terminal (and likewise the current) is a linear function of the (only) excitation, the voltage source externally attached to the port.

This implies two key things:

- First, if there is no external excitation, the voltage and current at the port are 0. This should make intuitive sense - the voltage from the dependent source is proportional to some excitation, but there is not excitation to drive the dependent source to produce its own nonzero voltage and current. Thus, the Thevenin voltage is zero.
- Second, because the circuit is linear, the voltage and current at the port are related proportionally. This means that the circuit's behavior is still representable as a Thevenin impedance. Given the active source, it's plausible that the effective impedance need not necessarily be positive -it could be zero, infinite, or negative depending on the exact topology, and the circuit must be solved to find its value.

> But, if there is a voltage or current source in the load section then the circuit would have power (not dead) and therefore there'd be a voltage drop across Vx so, the dependent source would have a voltage produced over it therefore negating the fact that Vth is equal to 0 in this case.

There is no contradiction here. The voltage drop and current are adequately represented by the Thevenin *impedance* component of the Thevenin equivalent. In the end, the Thevenin equivalent is an affine relationship of the form

$$ V_x = V_{th} + I_x R_{th} $$

with the exact form and sign depending on the sign convention you choose, and the proportional relationship between e.g. an applied current and the voltage seen at the port is perfectly represented by that impedance term, even if it's physically realized by some kind of active circuit rather than just a network of resistors.

Comment: Ahh, so the source can be represented as a 'negative' resistance which gets combined with the other resistances in the circuit. That explains why you sometimes get a negative resistance with dependent sources. Because, the independent sources, are written as a Thevenin voltage, and the dependent sources are linked to the other resistances so they just get expressed as a negative resistance. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @analysis101 yep, it has that effect - although it's not always quite a resistance (positive or negative) until you do some more analysis, since the controlling voltage and actual voltage are different nodes, and voltage/voltage doesn't have units of ohms. (Compare with the case where you model a resistor as a VCCS or CCVS with the controlling voltage across the resistor and controlling current through it)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the rightmost 1V source doesn't belong to the original circuit, it's a later scribble and should be wiped off. I guess also that B is the lowest horizontal wire in the circuit.

Assume there's voltage =Vth between A and B. When writing proper circuit analysis equations and eliminating node voltage V1 you get 2 seemingly contradicting equations. One says that Vth = P * Vx where P is a constant. The other says that Vth = Q * Vx.

Both P and Q are expressions which contain the resistances and the dependent source factor.

Of course, both equations can be fulfilled at the same time only in 2 cases:

Case1: Vx = Vth = 0

Case2: P = Q and in that case any Vth is as good. The circuit happens to be an active circuit which can settle to any Vth and stay there. P=Q is a condition between the resistances and the dependent source factor. Of course that's  generally not possible in any practical circuit, because exact resistor values are impossible to make in practice.

One simple dependent source circuit does not have that problem:

[image]

But it's still nothing more than a trick, because such dependent source is not available.